# python xpath : extract only few items from tables

Tags: python, html, xpath

I want to extract only few items from the html which is a table.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0" class="TableBorderBottom">     
    <tr>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">No.</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Name</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Stock<br>Code</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Rem</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Last<br>Done</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader" width="55">Chg</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">% Chg</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Vol<br>('00)</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Buy Vol<br>('00)</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Buy</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Sell</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">Sell Vol<br>('00)</td>
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeader">High</td>                    
      <td class="tblBursaSummHeaderRect">Low</td>
    </tr>       
            <tr>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow">1</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow"><a href="/tools.pl?action=factsheet&id=8494WA">LBI CAPITAL BHD-WARRANT A 08/8</a> (LBICAP-WA)</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">8494WA</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">s</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">0.160</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right"><img src="/images/upArrow.gif" border=0>&nbsp;<span class=tblUp>+0.120</span></td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">300.0</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">341,238</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">745</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">0.160</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">0.160</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">1,049</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRow Right">0.185</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSEvenRowRight Right">0.040</td>      
            </tr>           
            <tr>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow">2</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow"><a href="/tools.pl?action=factsheet&id=7091WA">UNIMECH GROUP BHD-WA13/18</a> (UNIMECH-WA)</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">7091WA</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">s</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">0.070</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right"><img src="/images/upArrow.gif" border=0>&nbsp;<span class=tblUp>+0.040</span></td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">133.3</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">261,521</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">8,468</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">0.065</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">0.070</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">5,008</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRow Right">0.080</td>
              <td class="tblBursaSOddRowRight Right">0.040</td>   
            </tr>           
            <tr>
```

My desired output is from Stock, Last done and Change. So the desirable output is

```
8494WA
0.160
+0.120
7091WA
0.070
+0.040
```

I able to extract the data but I need three lines of code but I prefer a one line code that can do the same works.

```
page_gain = requests.get('url')
gain = html.fromstring(page_gain.content)
stock = gain.xpath('//table[@class="TableBorderBottom"]/tr/td[3]/text()')
>>> ['Stock', 'Code', '8494WA', '7091WA']
gain.xpath('//table[@class="TableBorderBottom"]/tr/td[5]/text()')
>>>['Last', 'Done', '0.145', '0.075']
gain.xpath('//td/span/text()')
>>>['+0.120', '+0.070']
```

Notice that I also wish to eliminate the string 'Stock', 'Code','Last','Done' in the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process each row in the loop and get information you want from it:

```
data = []
for data_row in gain.xpath('//table[@class="TableBorderBottom"]/tr[position() > 1]'):
    stock = data_row.xpath('./td[3]/text()')[0]
    last_done = data_row.xpath('./td[5]/text()')[0]
    change = data_row.xpath('./td[6]/span/text()')[0]

    data.append({ "Stock": stock, "Last Done": last_done, "Change": change })
```